# How To integrate POS tagger with SentiWordNet algorithm

Tags: java, pos-tagger, senti-wordnet

```
Here is my SentiWorNet Algo:



public class SWN3 {

private String pathToSWN = "C:/Users/RAHUL/Desktop/SWN/SentiWordNet_3.0.0.txt";
        private HashMap<String, Double>_dict;

        public SWN3(){

            _dict = new HashMap<String, Double>();
            HashMap<String, Vector<Double>> _temp = new HashMap<String, Vector<Double>>();
            try{
                BufferedReader csv =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToSWN));
                String line = "";           
                while((line = csv.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String[] data = line.split("\t");
                    Double score = Double.parseDouble(data[2])-Double.parseDouble(data[3]);
                    String[] words = data[4].split(" ");
                    for(String w:words)
                    {
                        String[] w_n = w.split("#");
                        w_n[0] += "#"+data[0];
                        int index = Integer.parseInt(w_n[1])-1;
                        if(_temp.containsKey(w_n[0]))
                        {
                            Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(w_n[0]);
                            if(index>v.size())
                                for(int i = v.size();i<index; i++)
                                    v.add(0.0);
                            v.add(index, score);
                            _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Vector<Double> v = new Vector<Double>();
                            for(int i = 0;i<index; i++)
                                v.add(0.0);
                            v.add(index, score);
                            _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Set<String> temp = _temp.keySet();
                for (Iterator<String> iterator = temp.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                    String word = iterator.next();
                    Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(word);
                    double score = 0.0;
                    double sum = 0.0;
                    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
                        score += ((double)1/(double)(i+1))*v.get(i);
                    for(int i = 1; i<=v.size(); i++)
                        sum += (double)1/(double)i;
                    score /= sum;
                    String sent = "";               
                    if(score>=0.75)
                        sent = "strong_positive";
                    else
                    if(score > 0.50 && score<0.75)
                        sent = "moderately_positive";
                    else
                        if(score > 0.25 && score>=0.50)
                            sent = "positive";
                    else
                    if(score > 0 && score>=0.25)
                        sent = "weak_positive";
                    else
                    if(score < 0 && score>=-0.25)
                        sent = "weak_negative";
                    else
                    if(score < -0.25 && score>=-0.5)
                        sent = "negative";
                    else
                        if(score < -0.50 && score>-0.75)
                            sent = "moderately_negative";
                    else
                    if(score<=-0.75)
                        sent = "strong_negative";
                    _dict.put(word, score);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}        
        }

public Double extract(String word)
{
   Double total = new Double(0);
    if(_dict.get(word+"#n") != null)
         total = _dict.get(word+"#n") + total;
    if(_dict.get(word+"#a") != null)
        total = _dict.get(word+"#a") + total;
    if(_dict.get(word+"#r") != null)
        total = _dict.get(word+"#r") + total;
    if(_dict.get(word+"#v") != null)
        total = _dict.get(word+"#v") + total;
    return total;
}



public static String SentiWord(String stri) {
    SWN3 test = new SWN3();
    String sentence=stri;
    String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+"); 
    double totalScore = 0;
    for(String word : words) {
        word = word.replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z\\s])", "");
        if (test.extract(word) == null)
            continue;
        totalScore += test.extract(word);
    }

    String sent = "";               
    if(totalScore>=0.75)
        sent = "strong_positive";
    else
    if(totalScore > 0.25 && totalScore<0.75)
        sent = "positive";
   ....
   ....

    return sent;
}

}
```

And here is my Pos Tagger method:

```
public class TagText {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
ClassNotFoundException {

// Initialize the tagger
MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("taggers/english-left3words-distsim.tagger");

// The sample string
String sample = "This is a sample text";

// The tagged string
String tagged = tagger.tagString(sample);

//output the tagged sample string onto your console
System.out.println("Input: " + sample);
System.out.println("Output: "+ tagged);
}
}
```

I need POS Tagger to be integrated with SentiwordNet.I am trying to make a system for Sentimental analysis. Right now this SentiwordNet code is working fine without pos tagging but not giving good results.  I just cannot figure it out. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could adapt your `extract` method in `SWN3` like this:

```
public Double extract(String word, String tail) {
    if (tail.contains("NN") || tail.contains("NNS")
            || tail.contains("NNP")
            || tail.contains("NNPS"))
        return _dict.get(word + "#n");
    else if (tail.contains("VB") || tail.contains("VBD")
            || tail.contains("VBG") || tail.contains("VBN")
            || tail.contains("VBP") || tail.contains("VBZ")) 
        return _dict.get(word + "#v"); 
    else if (tail.contains("JJ") || tail.contains("JJR")
            || tail.contains("JJS"))
        return _dict.get(word + "#a");
    else if (tail.contains("RB") || tail.contains("RBR")
            || tail.contains("RBS"))
        return _dict.get(word + "#r");
    else
        return null;
}
```

It maps the [tags](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html) with the types of words as defined in `SentiWordNet`. I suggest to change your main method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("files/english-left3words-distsim.tagger");

    //String sample = "This is a sample text";
    String sample = "It works much better with this great example!";
    sample = sample.replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z\\s])", "");
    String[] words = sample.split("\\s+");

    String taggedSample = tagger.tagString(sample);
    String[] taggedWords = taggedSample.split("\\s+");
    System.out.println(tagger.tagString(sample));

    double totalScore = 0;
    SWN3 test = new SWN3();
    System.out.println("-----------");
    for (int i=0; i<taggedWords.length;i++) {
        String tail = taggedWords[i].substring(words[i].length() + 1);
        Double score = null;
        if(tail!=null{
            score = test.extract(words[i], tail);
            System.out.println(taggedWords[i] + "\t" + words[i] + "\t" + tail + "\t" + score);
        }
        if (score == null)
            continue;
        totalScore += score;
    }
    System.out.println("-----------");
    System.out.println(totalScore);
}
```

I used another sentence in `sample` where it works better. Note that tagging the sentence and tagging words individually can lead to different results.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Does it answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does. The program worked and definitely gives better results than before. Thanks for taking time :) Many regards

Comment: Extract method  is throwing null Pointer exception at line 1 i.e. sometimes at   --->   if (tail.contains("NN") || tail.contains("NNS"). Please help :(

Comment: I just made a change in the code. The code above gives you the idea how to integrate SWN3 with Stanford POS tagger, you should make it more robust and when exceptions occur, put break points to understand the problem. Good luck.